# Django how to custom inline error messages

Tags: django

I am trying to show a inline error messages when user update the location and name pair with an exist one.
But I have no idea how to custom it.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
class LocationUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.location = form.instance.cylinder.upper()
        condition = {
            'location': form.instance.location,
            'name': form.instance.name,
        }
        item = Address.objects.filter(**condition)
        if item.count() > 0:
            # should I custom error message here?
            return super().form_invalid(form)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `form_valid()` for validations. You should do so in your form class.

In you form class, use `clean_FIELDNAME` to validate the field.

```
#forms.py

class MyForm(ModelForm):
...
    def clean_location(self):
        location = self.cleaned_data['location']
        self.instance.location = self.instance.cylinder.upper()
        condition = {
            'location': self.instance.location,
            'name': self.instance.name,
        }
        item = Address.objects.filter(**condition)
        if item.count() > 0:
            raise ValidationError("Custom message")
    return location
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform)